# navigation in frame by changing the source through WPF view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, navigation, frame

I am new to WPF and MVVM. I have Frame in mainWindowView in my WPF application. I have bind the source of frame to SourcePage property of view model:

```
<Frame Name="frame" Content="Frame" Source="{Binding Path=SourcePage, Source={StaticResource WindowViewModel},  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

In view model,

```
public string SourcePage
{
  get
  {
    return _sourcePage;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value != null)
    {
      _sourcePage = value;
       OnPropertyChanged("SourcePage");
    }
  }
}
```

Initially I have loaded selectTest view in that frame by setting sourcepage value in viewmodel constructor:

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   SourcePage ="Std.User/SelectTest.xaml";
}
```

Now on click of button, I need to perform some DB operations and after that I want to load another view in that frame.

Hi Colin, Thanks for ur immediate reply. But I have tried the same and it is not working as expected. Here is my code

```
public ICommand StartTestCommand
{
  get
  {
    if (_startTest == null)
    {
     _startTest = new DelegateCommand(StartTest);
    }
    return _startTest;
  }
}
private void StartTest()
{
  MainWindowViewModel mwvm = new MainWindowViewModel();
  mwvm.SourcePage = "std.user/ChangePassword2.xaml";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this:

1. Expose a command (`ICommand`) from your view model as a property. This can be bound to a `Button`, which when clicked will execute your command. See the [Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) on MSDN  for examples.
2. Perform the database logic you require in your view model when the command is executed
3. When it has completed, change the `SourcePage` property to your next page. The view will update automatically.

You might also want to add an `IsBusy` boolean property to your view model which is true whilst your database activities are being processed. You can use this to disable you view via binding.